# Change Windows Desktop via Powershell (unpin group from Start, Notifications, Task Manager etc.)

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I would like to change some settings for the Windows Desktop View via Powershell. Unfortunately, this does not work at all. Currently I would like to change the following things:

1. Unpin group from Start
   [Unpin group from Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAr8L.png)

My approach:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\Cache\DefaultAccount\ | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*start.tilegrid$windows.data.curatedtilecollection.tilecollection*"} | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

2. Notifications "Expand" and "Clear all notifications"
   [Notifications "Expand" and "Clear all notifications"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjNCR.png)

My approach:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Quick Actions\Control Center\QuickActionsStateCapture" -Name "Toggles" -Type String -Value "Toggles,Microsoft.QuickAction.Location:false,Microsoft.QuickAction.BlueLightReduction:false,Microsoft.QuickAction.AllSettings:false,Microsoft.QuickAction.AvailableNetworks:false,Microsoft.QuickAction.Connect:false,Microsoft.QuickAction.Project:false,Microsoft.QuickAction.Vpn:false,Microsoft.QuickAction.QuietHours:false,Microsoft.QuickAction.ScreenClipping:false" -Force
```

3. Task Manager
   [Task Manager > More details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u43GQ.png)
   [Performance > CPU > Change graph to > Logical processors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1bAR.png)

My approach:

```
New-Item -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion -Name TaskManager –Force
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TaskManager" -Name "StartUpTab" -Type DWord -Value 1 -Force
```

4. Language
   [Remove Languages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c4uf.png)
   [Download Language pack, Handwriting, Speech](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHzht.png)

My approach:

```
Add-WindowsPackage -Online -PackagePath .\lp_de-CH.cab
$ll = New-WinUserLanguageList -Language $language
Set-WinUserLanguageList $ll -Force
$LangList = Get-WinUserLanguageList
$MarkedLang = $LangList | where LanguageTag -eq "fr-CH"
$LangList.Remove($MarkedLang)
$MarkedLang = $LangList | where LanguageTag -eq "en-us"
$LangList.Remove($MarkedLang)
```

Unfortunately, it does not work with it. Does anyone have an idea about one of the points?

Thank you very much and best regards

Comment: Does _"does not work"_ mean you get error messages? PLease show these in full in the question

Comment: Hello and thank you for the answer. The commands do not bring any message at all, but also have no effect. My question is of general nature, how to solve this. I make a number of adjustments via PowerShell, but I have not found any suitable commands for these 4 things and tried them myself. Therefore my general question how this can be solved (gladly also differently from my approach).

Comment: Have you tried restarting after making the changes?

Comment: Hello and also thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, this also has no effect. Maybe someone else has an idea how to set the settings automatically (via script)?